# How do I get back to the original git bash UI which is now replaced by the cmd (black interface)?

Tags: git, git-bash

I recently updated  `Git bash` and after updating the normal UI that I used to get was replaced by the Windows `cmd` UI. How can I roll back or change back to the original UI for `Git bash`?

[image: Here's is a screenshot of what it looks like now.]

Comment: What the "normal UI" looked like? Was is _also_ a command-line window but with the "Git bash" title (or something like this)?

Comment: Have you tried to re-install it, selecting the option to use git bash instead of cmd?

Comment: @kostix a command-line interface with the "Git bash" title.

Comment: OK, so after performing _what action, exactly_ do you get this plain `cmd.exe` window? Do you activate some Start menu option? If yes, then which exactly? GfW installs/upates its menu under the Start→Applications (the regular way, that is); does an attempt to activate "Git Bash" from there starts you Git Bash? Is there even an option named like that? I mean, your question lacks too many details, unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah... I didn't have any idea about explaining the problem in a proper sense. But I installed it, and then followed what @LeonardoAlvesMachado said. Thank you so much though for your input. Appreciate it.

Comment: I think while updating my Git bash, I chose it to open with cmd in one of the steps which I unchecked this time and got back the old UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to put in an answer the suggestion I've made on the comments, that worked out.

Re-install git, selecting the option to use `git bash` instead of `cmd`.

Comment: @rajat-gupta, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) this answer.